# Absolute Value of a Integral, separation

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, absolute-value

This is a homework exercise, and ''Thomas early trascendentals'' book vol.4 says in property that :

Def: To integrate an absolute value function, we have to look for specific cases when ;
$ v(t)\leqslant 0 ; v(t)\geqslant  0$

$v(t)$ in this case is,$  \frac{x-2}{x+5} for\quad I\in[0,4] $

Furthermore, in my following steps I concluded that i must separate the integrals in sum :

$\int_0^2\left(\frac{-(x-2)}{x+5}\right) dx  + \int_2^4\left(\frac{x-2}{x+5}\right)dx $ 
I am right with that intervals?

And that is

$\int_0^4\lvert (\frac{x-2}{x+5})\rvert dx $

Comment: It looks correct to me.

Comment: I concur. Your integration setup does look correct.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.